# Multiple ajax request calls.

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm trying to fetch the status of an running request, and update it on the page while the first rquest is running. but it isn't updateing while the request is running, it updates only on the beginning and at the end. whats wrong?

here is my code:

```
    function get_remote() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Html->url(array('action'=>'getstatus','test')) ?>",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#info").html(response);
                console.log('ok');
                if(response != 'finished')
                    setTimeout("get_remote()", 10);
            }
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        $('#initimport').click(function(){      
           get_remote();
           $.ajax({
                url: "Html->url(array('action'=>'initimport'))?>",
                success: function () {
                    console.log('success', this);
                }
           });
           return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I would try, I think you need a better way to log the time. I am not sure what you are doing now to test the times but here is a good way.

Get Firebug for Firefox if you haven't already done so.

Open Firebug and go to the net tab. Make sure you enable it.

As you click each button you should see each request coming in. If you click each button, you don't see the next request starting until the previous request has ended then this tells me there is something wrong in javascript. However, I am guessing you should the beginning of each bar to be 1 second apart. Do this and let us know what you see.

**Edit**

I think I found you problem. I am guessing you are using sleep function in php. The sleep function sleeps for the current session. If you open up 3 tabs, and put the ajax url, you will notice the same behavior. 5, 10, then 15s for each tab to finish. I tried googling and found the same results with other people. This is probably because PHP is not really multithreaded. I suggest using a different framework.

Comment: thanks a lot, there was a problem in my php code ... i used sessions in php, after removing the session variables and useing simple files to store .. it works